# AWS Cognito: while user is enabled with "adminSetUserPassword" then email to user with password should trigger automatically

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

when user is enabled with **"cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminSetUserPassword"**
Email should trigger automatically to user with that password

below code is enabling user but it is not sending emails to user.

**Can any one suggest how to implement this scenario**

```
  let params: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AdminSetUserPasswordRequest = {
    UserPoolId: this.cognitoUtil.getUserPool().getUserPoolId(),
    Username: User.Email,
    Password: User.Password,
    Permanent: false
  };

  let cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminSetUserPassword(params, (err: AWS.AWSError, res: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AdminSetUserPasswordResponse) => {
      if (res)
        return resolve(res);
      return reject(err);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cognito doesn't send an email when it comes to admin force setting a password for the user using the `adminSetUserPassword` you have to do it manually using SNS or email provider of choice

This can be done when you do this sdk function on the backend then when it finishes, you would send an email/sms to that user with that password